# Do reverse entries for name-server, need to match the mailserver name?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I need to setup PTR for a domain and lets say my domain is `domain.com` and I have my email addresses like `email.address@domain.com`.

I came over [this mailing-list article that says:](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2011-November/085635.html)

> The reverse entries for your nameserver don't have to match your
>   mailserver name but they must be consistent, i.e. the reverse must
>   resolve forward to the IP addresses.

Does this mean that I could have this `PTR` record:

```
44.33.22.11.in-addr.arpa  300  IN  PTR subdomain.domain.com.
88.77.66.55.in-addr.arpa  300  IN  PTR subdomain2.domain.com.
```

and this `A` records:

```
subdomain.domain.com.   3256    IN  A   11.22.33.44
subdomain2.domain.com.  3256    IN  A   55.66.77.88
```

and it will work ?

Or do I need to have also:

```
domain.com. 3256    IN  A   11.22.33.44
domain.com. 3256    IN  A   55.66.77.88
```

or

```
domain.com. 3256    IN  MX  subdomain.domain.com. 
domain.com. 3256    IN  MX  subdomain2.domain.com.
```

for everything to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is what it means. You don't need the domain.com entry, just the A and PTR records for the mailserver's IP

Comment: That means that I should have both `domain.com. 3256 IN MX subdomain.domain.com.` and
`domain.com. 3256 IN MX subdomain2.domain.com.` to make it work?

Comment: You don't need the MX entries as far as I know. As long as the IP of the Mailserver can be reverse-looked-up and then forward-looked-up again, you should be fine. Mail sending is not directly connected with mail receiving `(MX)`

Comment: You don't need any domain.com record for it to work. Subdomains only.